# Nunit TestCaseSource with setName also shows original test in testexplorer

Tags: c#, testing, nunit

I'm attempting to use TestCaseSource to re-use the test with different data. Here I'm trying to give my tests their own name with the 'setName' property which works fine. My issue is that the original test also shows up in the testexplorer. It doesn't seem possible to run. How can I get rid of it in the test explorer?

Simple reproduction:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
    [TestCaseSource(nameof(MyTestData))]
    [Category(name: "MyCategory")]
    public void OriginalTest(string first, string second)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> MyTestData
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData("firstString", "secondString").SetName("FirstTest");
            yield return new TestCaseData("firstString", "secondString").SetName("SecondTest");
        }
    }
}
```

My test explorer looks like this

[image]

Comment: Try to run all of them and see if the explorer refreshes itself.

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately. Just leaves the blue mark as in the screenshot

Comment: Which test-runner are you using? From VS? ReSharper? And which framework? NUnit? Or VSTests?

Comment: VS test-runner and NUnit framework

Comment: What version of the NUnit framework? Of the NUnit 3 test adapter? Of VS?

Comment: use TestName if available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to be a problem with the adapter.

I was having this same issue, using `SetArgDisplayNames` instead, which, while not providing the expected visual result, was the best fit for this kind of usage until the problem was fixed.

Updating NUnit3TestAdapter to [v3.16.0](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Adapter-Release-Notes) the problem no longer occurred:

[image: VS Test Adapter example]